# Linux from scratch Installation of Cross GCC (recipe for target 'configure-target-libstdc++-v3' failed)

Tags: gcc, libstdc++, linux-from-scratch

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:10457: recipe for target 'configure-target-libstdc++-v3' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-4.9.2/build'
```

---

I am trying to Build LFS, in GCC Module, make has this error, and I have no idea on how to enable that dynamic linker after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES, and what is wrong with the libstdc++.

I have installed all necessary tools according to lfs. I have a Intel Pentium Processor, 64 bit host Elementary os 0.4(loki)

Necessary Package Details.

```
     bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release
       /bin/sh -> /bin/bash
       Binutils: (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
       bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.4
       /usr/bin/yacc -> /usr/bin/bison.yacc
       bzip2,  Version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010.
       Coreutils:  8.25
       diff (GNU diffutils) 3.3
       find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
       GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
       /usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
       gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
       g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
       (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu5) 2.23
       grep (GNU grep) 2.25
       gzip 1.6
       Linux version 4.4.0-59-generic (buildd@lgw01-11) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017
        m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.17
        GNU Make 4.1
        GNU patch 2.7.5
        Perl version='5.22.1';
        sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
        tar (GNU tar) 1.28
        texi2any (GNU texinfo) 6.1
        xz (XZ Utils) 5.1.0alpha
        g++ compilation OK
```